# elFinder with NFS: Unable to upload "image.jpg"

Tags: php, nfs, upload, codeigniter

I have a NFS mount with permissions 770 on user:group "nfsbackup:nfsbackuo" with www-data as member of group nfsbackup.

This is my server connector configuration in PHP, using CodeIgniter 2, working:

```
$opts = array(
    'debug' => true, 
    'roots' => array(
      array( 
        'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', 
        'path'   => '/opt/upload/',  
        'uploadMaxSize' => '1M',
        'disabled' => array('extract', 'archive', 'mkdir', 'mkfile'),
        'tmbCrop'    => false,
        'tmbPath'    => null,
        'copyOverwrite' => false,
        'tmpPath' => '/opt/upload.tmp/',
        'debug' => true,
      ) 
    )
  );
```

Permissions for the root folder:

```
755 root:root
```

Permissions for the two folders:

```
770 nfsbackup:nfsbackup
```

Same configuration on NFS, not working:

```
  $opts = array(
    'debug' => true, 
    'roots' => array(
      array( 
        'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', 
        'path'   => '/mnt/nfsbackup/upload/',  
        'uploadMaxSize' => '1M',
        'disabled' => array('extract', 'archive', 'mkdir', 'mkfile'),
        'tmbCrop'    => false,
        'tmbPath'    => null,
        'copyOverwrite' => false,
        'tmpPath' => '/mnt/nfsbackup/upload.tmp/',
        'debug' => true,
      ) 
    )
  );
```

Permissions for the root folder:

```
755 root:root
```

Permissions for the two folders:

```
770 nfsbackup:nfsbackup
```

When uploading, I get after a time waiting (timeout somewhere? 3.5 seconds) Unable to upload "image.jpg". The file is created, but empty (filesize 0).

Answer to the client:

```
{"added":[],"warning":["errUploadFile","image.jpg"],"debug":{"connector":"php","phpver":"5.3.3-7+squeeze19","time":25.02913403511,"memory":"9982Kb \/ 9059Kb \/ 128M","upload":"","volumes":[{"id":"l1_","name":"localfilesystem","mimeDetect":"finfo","imgLib":"imagick"}],"mountErrors":[]}}
```

Also tested with 777 on /mnt/nfsbackup/. The mounted drive is mapped to nfsbackup:nfsbackup on NFS-server (same id).

This is my client connector configuration in PHP:

```
var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
    // lang: 'ru',             // language (OPTIONAL)
    url : "http://server.com/api/connector",
    debug : true,
}).elfinder('instance');
```

What can I do? No errors in log output.